# Open hyperlink with macro in all sheets of a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

I have one Excel workbook with three sheets (sheet 1, sheet 2 & sheet 3), in sheet1 in B1 cell I have hyperlink which I open with the recorded macro command, however when I run the macro in sheet no. 2 then command fails with error run-time error '9'.

Please help as I want to use this command in such a way that if I have opened sheet2 or sheet 3 then still it may open the hyperlink of sheet 1.

Comment: try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").Hyperlinks(1)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("B1").Select
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

You need to tell VBA that the hyperlink is on another sheet if your referencing it from a different sheet. By adding `Worksheets("Sheet1")` your telling VBA to always look at `Sheet1` regardless of what sheet is actually activated. The `Range("B1")` is simply narrowing the range in which a hyperlink can be found and deemed as the 1st hyperlink

Comment: Answers work much better with text explaining them. Explanations facilitate learning.